# Generate UUID with fix String

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

I want to create UUID with fix string like in following example.

> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002

Is there any way to generate UUID with fix string.

Comment: Those are not valid UUID strings. The first part should have 8 digits, not 9.

Comment: Show actual code in your question demonstrating your issue because it works just fine if you remove the extra 0.

Comment: Apple is using RFC 4122 in the implementation of UUID. So if you generate UUID by `UUID().uuidString` method then it's okay. Otherwise, if you create the uuid by yourself then you have to follow the RFC 4122.

Comment: @rmaddy yes it's working fine now

Answer (score 1):

From Apple Document

```
/// Create a UUID from a string such as "E621E1F8-C36C-495A-93FC-0C247A3E6E5F".
/// 
/// Returns nil for invalid strings.
public init?(uuidString string: __shared String)
```

Your fixed strings are not valid (9 digits in the first component instead of 8)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
000000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
```

To

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
```